# How to copy file from file location list in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If you don't want to read the whole story, you can skip to the next paragraph.
So I found a YouTube video of how to make file in usb drive to autorun when the usb is inserted. Then I found and program that shows you all passwords saved in the browser (these passwords are stored in  a database file on your computer). So the program gets the file with the passwords and writes them on another file. But the problem is that the antivirus is blocking it every time. It's saying that there is unwanted app and I have to allow it.

So I started writing my own code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem change to the correct directory
cd /d C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge
rem count the files
dir /b "Login Data" /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > %temp%\count
set /p _count=<%temp%\count
rem cleanup
del %temp%\count
rem output the number of files
echo Files found : %_count%
rem list the files
echo Files Paths :
dir /b "Login Data" /s > D:\Folder\dir.txt
pause
endlocal
```

So what this does is finding all the files with specific name and writes their paths to a txt file. But I can't seem to understand how to make it reading these paths from the file and copying the files to the usb drive.

The count and pause functions are just to know if the program is really finding all the files called "Login Data"

I watched YouTube tutorials, searched in google, asked friends and nothing worked.

Comment: Your problem appears to be that you have a list of filenames in `D:\Folder\dir.txt` and you want to copy each of those files to your USB drive. Since each of those filenames will be "Login Data", you could concatenate the contents of each file into a file on your USB drive or you could copy the files in the list to the USB with a new name. Which way do you want to jump?

Comment: @Magoo I think connecting the files in one bigger file is the better option

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%e in (D:\Folder\dir.txt) do type "%%e">>d:\folder\combinedlogindata.txt` should do that for you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `for` command to handle each file found by the `dir` command. Note the for documentation (for /?), %%i will only work in batch files, at command line you would use %i instead.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b "Login Data" /s') do copy "%%i" "f:\path\"
```

`f:\path\` would be the target path at the USB drive.
On the other hand you do not need the `dir` command as the `copy` command can filter by itself. Bye the way I do not understand the filter `Login Data` as is seems to be only one file. Eg. `dir "Login Data*"` would result in a list of files starting with `"Login Data"`.